# Why cant I use the message feature provided by django?

Tags: html, django, django-views

In my view (Part of it):

```
from django.contrib import messages

try:
 selection=request.POST.get('portrange')
except:
 messages.warning(request, "Please select the ports")
```

In my html (Part of it):

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-10">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="port_range">Port range</label>
     <textarea class="form-control" id="port_range" rows="5" name ="portrange"></textarea>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How come my messages.warning is not appearing if i have no input in my textarea (portrange)? Am i doing something wrong for django message? All I know is i have to import: `from django.contrib import messages` When i press the submit button, it just redirect to another page without showing the warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to display the messages in your template:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

[Also docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages)